# OAuth2 flows using Refit with Asp Net Core 2.1

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, oauth, oauth-2.0, refit

Well, I have a WebApi using Asp Net Core 2.1 that have some security endpoints, so I have the following:

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
              options.DefaultAuthenticateScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
              options.DefaultChallengeScheme = JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            }).AddJwtBearer(options =>
            {
              options.Authority = configuration["Authorization:Domain"];
              options.Audience = configuration["Authorization:ApiIdentifier"];
              options.TokenValidationParameters = new TokenValidationParameters()
              {
                ValidateLifetime = configuration["Authorization:ValidateLifetime"] == null ? true :
                                   Boolean.Parse(configuration["Authorization:ValidateLifetime"])
              };
              options.RequireHttpsMetadata = configuration["Authorization:RequireHttpsMetadata"] == null ?
                                              true : Boolean.Parse(configuration["Authorization:RequireHttpsMetadata"]);
            });
```

This works very well when someone calls my API, the validation is OK. I'm using http://auth0.com/ as an authorization provider.

Now I need to call other APIs that have security endpoints too, using **Authorization Bearer Token (JWT)**. The flow that I should use in this case is **Client Credentials**. So, I have the steps:

1. Someone calls my API
2. My API validates Jwt Token using auth0.com as authorization provider
3. I need to call other API, so I'm using Refit Library

My Refit interface:

```
public interface IUserInfoApi
  {
    [Get("/api/v2/users/{userId}")]
    [Headers("Authorization: Bearer")]
    Task<UserInfoDto> GetUserInfoAsync(string userId);
  }
```

And I created I handler to add Bearer token to my request:

```
//refit apis
      services.AddRefitClient<IUserInfoApi>()
      .AddHttpMessageHandler<AuthorizationMessageHandler>()
        .ConfigureHttpClient(c => c.BaseAddress = new Uri(configuration["Api:UserInfo"]));
```

And my handler:

```
protected override async Task<HttpResponseMessage> SendAsync(HttpRequestMessage request, CancellationToken cancelToken)
    {
      HttpRequestHeaders headers = request.Headers;
      AuthenticationHeaderValue authHeader = headers.Authorization;
      if (authHeader != null)
        headers.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue(authHeader.Scheme, JWT_TOKEN);

      return await base.SendAsync(request, cancelToken);
    }
```

This works, but I think is too much manually and error-prone:

1. There is a lot of OAuth2 flows to implement manually, to generate a token (client credentials, implicit flow, authorization code flow and others).
2. I have to implement refresh token logic.
3. I have to implement some logic to reuse token if the expiration time is valid yet, instead generate a new token every time (hit /token endpoint every time without needed).

I worked a lot with Spring Security framework, and I can just say: *"Spring, I'm using OAuth here, so insert Bearer token in every HTTP requests, please"*. Spring, intercepts all requests that I set in configuration and OAuth flow is respected (Client Credentials, Authorization COde Flow, and others), it's transparent for me, I don't need wast my time with it.

**There is any way to do it in Asp Net Core 2.1 or I need to implement manually the token generate flow?**